# How to access object within class-based views mixin?

Tags: django

I use class-based view to update my model:

```
class BlogUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model=Blog

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(BlogUpdateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['author'] = get_object_or_404(User,
            username__iexact=self.kwargs['username'])
        return context
```

I want to follow the DRY principle and avoid repeating `get_context_data` in every view function. The question is nearly the same as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10337290/1061572). Relying on the answer given by [@Jj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/43490/jj) I suppose my class to look like this:

```
class BlogMixin(object):
    def get_author(self):
      # How to get author?
      return author

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
      context = super(BlogMixin, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
      context['author'] = self.get_author()
      return context
```

My question is: How can I access object in mixin class?

**UPDATE**

Answer is given in mongoose_za comment. I can get author with this line:

```
author = User.objects.get(username__iexact=self.kwargs['username'])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your will land up something like this:

```
class BlogMixin(object):
    def get_author(self):
      # How to get author?
      # Assuming user is logged in. If not you must create him
      author = self.request.user
      return author

class BlogUpdateView(BlogMixin, UpdateView):
    model=Blog

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(BlogUpdateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['author'] = self.get_author()
        return context
```

When you do `context = super(BlogUpdateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)` then **context** will be your object.

---

First you add your mixin into the class constructor.

As you see here:

```
class BlogUpdateView(BlogMixin, UpdateView):
```

Now the base `def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):` will be overridden by your `def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):` from the BlogMixin mixin.

BUT you have also specified a `def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):` in your `class BlogUpdateView(UpdateView):` and in the end this is the `get_context_data` that will take effect.

Mixins are tricky to get the hang of. I feel it's best to learn by viewing other peoples examples. Take a look [here](http://brack3t.com/our-custom-mixins.html)

**Edit**: Realised that perhaps I didn't answer your question properly. If you want to have access to an object within your mixin you have to pass it in. For example I'll pass the context object to the mixin:

```
class BlogMixin(object):
    def get_author(self, context):
      # This is how to get author object
      author = User.objects.get(username__iexact=self.kwargs['username'])
      return context

class BlogUpdateView(BlogMixin, UpdateView):
    model=Blog

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(BlogUpdateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        return self.get_author(context)
```

The code isn't tested but the idea should be right

Comment: mongoose_za, thanks for the answer! The problem with getting object is that author is not the same as `request.user`, e.g when admin updates other user's blog entry. We have to get author out of `username` key, that is passed via GET (in url).

Comment: OK. In that case you just change this line `context['author'] = self.request.user` and find the user however you want. Probably something like `context['author'] = User.objects.get(username__iexact=self.kwargs['username'])`.

Comment: mongoose_za, I'm aware of how to use mixins, I just couldn't retrieve objects within mixin, and this was my question. Your last suggestion is working, thank you for that!

Comment: @VladT. sorry if my answer was verbose. at least the last suggestion helped :)

Comment: @VladT. If it did answer your question please tick the answer so the question can be marked as resolved. Thanks