# Grabbing current logged in user with Django class views?

Tags: python, django, view

I'm trying to grab the currently logged in user and display at the the top of every view. I've searched all over the place for this, but I can't ever find a straight answer for my problem.

I was able to get it in the form view, but for some reason I can't display it in a normal view. It's driving me nuts.

```
from django.http import HttpResponse, Http404
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView, FormView
from django.template import RequestContext, loader, Context
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from boards.models import Links, LinksCreateForm, Category
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


def get_user(request):
    current_user = request.get.user
    return current_user


class LinksListView(ListView):
    model = Links


class LinksDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Links


class LinksCreateView(FormView):
    template_name = 'boards/link_create.html'
    form_class = LinksCreateForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        name = form.cleaned_data['name']
        description = form.cleaned_data['description']
        user = self.request.user
        category = Category.objects.get(id=form.cleaned_data['category'].id)
        link = Links(name=name, description=description, user=user, category=category)
        link.save()
        self.success_url = '/boards/'

        return super(LinksCreateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In your generic view implementation you will need to extend `get_context_data`

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
# Call the base implementation first to get a context
        c = super(ReqListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        user = self.request.user
        return c
```

Then it depends on your requirements what you want to do with that.

[Extending generic view classes for common get_context_data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10337290/extending-generic-view-classes-for-common-get-context-data)

Comment: that solution is not really django-ish. See the answer sneawo's answer.

Comment: Well the question asked for the user in the view, not in the template. sneawo's answer is perfect otherwise.

Answer (score 10):

Within your view, you have access to the request (and therefore the user):

```
self.request.user
```

Since you are talking about displaying it at the top of a 'View', I believe you are wanting access to it in the template.

You should be able to access it in your template as:

```
{{ request.user }}
```

Comment: Easiest answer here.

Answer (score 6):

You can add `'django.core.context_processors.request'` to `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` in settings.py and then access current user as `{{ request.user }}`. If you haven't this variable, you can add it as:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
    'django.core.context_processors.debug',
    'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
    'django.core.context_processors.media',
    'django.core.context_processors.static',
    'django.core.context_processors.tz',
    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages'
)
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/settings/#std:setting-TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS

Answer (score 0):

adding to  template context processors as @sneawo pointed is the best way to go. however, I prefer **not to override** defaults, but to **extend** it. Like this:

```
from django.conf.global_settings import TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS as TCP
# ...
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = TCP + (
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
)
```

Why? Because the list of default context processors in django changes from version to version. Some built-in / shipped with (contrib) libraries depend on the default settings. In general, I believe it's better not to override the defaults unless you have to.